# Why were these "not an answer" flags disputed and/or rejected?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

See [How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c/2751112#2751112) and [How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c/1362840#1362840), these are clearly link-only answers. W/o the links these answers say nothing. These two flags were disputed.

Also [Why do I get these warnings in Visual C++ 2008 when building a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151298/why-do-i-get-these-warnings-in-visual-c-2008-when-building-a-struct/7151432#7151432), here a link to an existing answer is provided ([Why do I get these warnings in Visual C++ 2008 when building a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151298/c-warnings-on-vs2008/7151406#7151406)) and another link which is dead now. This flag was rejected by a moderator.

Comment: They're disputed because more users in the LQP queue marked them as no action needed, than voted to delete.  Given the comments on both posts, clearly *some* users voted to delete, just not enough.

Comment: I really wish we'd get rid of, or at least re-phrase, the "Not an answer" option.  It really does cause a lot of confusion, IMHO, and I feel like "Not an answer" questions pop up with regular occurance.

Comment: @Compass - those aren't low-quality either.  Low-quality is for unsalvageable, incoherent garbage.  As is the "Not an answer" option.

Comment: @Compass See [when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381)  Linking to an answer is not an answer.

Comment: I think I need a break from Stack Overflow, my memory seems to have overflowed and now I am confused. Be back tomorrow.

Comment: The second link has the title of the book and the chapter in it. Without the link you could still find the book and the chapter..

Comment: @MartijnPieters The point remains that the answer doesn't *answer the question*, rather it points to where you can go to find the answer.  It is not itself *an answer*.  Directions to where to find an answer, whether it be a hyperlink or the ISBN of a book, are not answers.

Comment: @Servy: it is a low quality answer; an *attempt* at answering. I know, it is a lot like the directions to the nearest bookshop rather than an answer itself. But it has been helpful to people, so perhaps it should be edited to include a summary of the answer from the book in it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Again, the stated policy is rather explicit:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381 Directions to the nearest bookshop is NAA.  The post itself needs to answer the question, such that there is no need for the reader to do anything other than read the answer to learn the answer to the question.  If the answer is edited to include enough information from that resource to completely answer the question (assuming the books licence allows for this), then it would become an answer.

Comment: @Servy - you are wasting your breath/fingers whatever, the *Summer of Love* has made everyone a language lawyer *"Technically, anything typed in the Answer box is an Answer, because it is labeled Answer"*. And *"at least they tried* is not defense. It is like saying *"well I worked really hard at failing"* should get you a gold star, you failed and you expended effort in doing so, fail^3!

Comment: Isn't there a "link-only answer" option to delete answers in the Low Quality Review Queue? Which would definitely make it an answer... just a low quality one worthy of deletion.

Comment: I think answers primarily consisting of a link should be acceptable, as long as the answer describes the nature of the information being linked to (so that I know what to expect and whether it is worth my time to click the link) and the link content is directly relevant.  In fact, in many cases linking should be PREFERRED over duplicating information found elsewhere, in my opinion.  I realize that's not the policy.  I just don't agree with the policy when taken too strictly (and the examples here take it too strictly).

Comment: If we insist that information available elsewhere be duplicated here rather than linked to, we a) lower the quality of information as it is condensed to fit into an answer, b) likely fail to adequately acknowledge the work and research done by others as they generated the information we would otherwise link to, and c) require extra effort that provides no additional value.

Comment: AMEN, @Darryl; I think having a summary or quote from the site but keeping a link giving adequate credit is the way to go.

Comment: A quote or summary and link are perfectly fine, @Jacob. [Just avoid doing one without the other.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 30):

Amusingly, I disputed the first two while clearing out the LQ review queue yesterday (there was a backlog of over 130 posts when I checked, which is too many to be left sitting there). Both posts had been in review for a while, unable to garner enough reviews to be deleted or dismissed.

I've no qualms about deleting such posts when they're created today, but removing them after 5 years because the flagger couldn't be bothered to edit? Meh. Neither one was completely lacking in information, and both had apparently been found useful by multiple readers over the past few years - even if the presentation isn't what we like here, that history is worth a few minutes of someone's time to salvage.

You have privileges on the site that let you do an awful lot to improve old content. Use 'em, don't throw up your hands and defer to others unless that's your *only* option. **Be the user-moderator your participation has earned you the right to be, not a helpless supplicant.**

Comment: **like the bold sentiment**

Answer (score 1):

- [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c/2751112#2751112) - This answer has little more than a link, but editing in the page title would put it over the bar required, so why not edit that information in instead of asking people to delete a potentially helpful answer? The link isn't dead. Anyone can edit that in. (Done.)
- [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c/1362840#1362840) - This answer has enough information to find the linked page even if the link does eventually die. This shouldn't have been flagged, so was rightly disputed.
- [Why do I get these warnings in Visual C++ 2008 when building a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151298/why-do-i-get-these-warnings-in-visual-c-2008-when-building-a-struct/7151432#7151432) - This has more information than just the two links. There's enough information there to answer the question, and probably to find the article originally linked to. I would have declined the flag too.

Comment: As per the stated policy on [what is not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) directing the user to where to go to find the answer is not an answer.  The fact that reading an answer would tell someone where else to go to find the answer (by, say, providing the identifying information of a book with the answer) is not an answer, and should be flagged.

Comment: @Servy That is not what that post says.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Servy Look at the examples of (admittedly bad) answers. "Look at manual for preg_split, third argument" is an attempt at an answer. It's just telling someone where to look, but giving them just enough information to find the answer.

Comment: Telling them what function/class to use is an answer in and of itself.  It's not that it's pointing to the documentation, it's that the information needed to answer the question, namely the class/function that accomplishes the goal, is listed.  The post in question doesn't actually provide any information that would help anyone understand what the answer is *in the actual answer*.  It is *purely* a way to find where the actual answer is.  In the examples in Shog's post the actual literal text of the answer provides a (low quality) answer.

Comment: To expand on my last comment, the two examples in Shog's question are answers because you can actually answer the question by *only* reading the post, and not going to any external resources the post directs you to.  You don't *need* to read the documentation referenced for that post to answer your question.  Even if there is no documentation, and you find nothing else besides what's in that post, you have learned something about how to solve this problem.  Providing the name of a book does none of those things.  Until you find the book it references you have learned *nothing*.

Comment: @Servy "Look at manual for preg_split, third argument" doesn't tell you the answer either, until you go to the manual and look at what the third argument of preg_split is. It just gives you enough useful information to find the answer. We shouldn't be flagging posts for deletion if they provide useful information. We should be editing them into shape, or using them to write new, better answers. Flagging them is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Reading the answer tells you that to solve your problem one needs to use the third parameter of preg_split.  I'd be willing to bet that you could rather easily figure out the answer from there without actually looking at the documentation, despite the fact that the answer is telling you to go there.  If the question is asking, "how do I limit the number of items split from a string" then knowing that the third parameter to preg_split accepts that limit then I have found my answer, without even needing to read the documentation.

Comment: I have to agree with @Servy on this one, but this is like when mommy and daddy are fighting so I'm gonna go hide my head under my pillow now!