# Is this a link only answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957466/how-to-create-an-on-off-switch-with-javascript-css/1957501#1957501)

> You mean something like IPhone checkboxes? http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html

and claimed in a custom flag that it was link only. There is no substance to the answer besides that link; and could easily have been a comment before an answer. My flag was declined as

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Can anyone explain why? Because I argue that [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957466/how-to-create-an-on-off-switch-with-javascript-css/12908811#12908811) on the same question is also link only.

> check out this generator: **On/Off FlipSwitch***
>   you can get various different style outcomes and its css only - no javascript!

*hyperlinked

Both answers are highly upvoted and one is accepted as an answer; does this make a difference?

Comment: @downvotes, any reason for the downvotes?

Comment: You're leaving out critical information in a bid to make your case: the answer that was declined has a lot of upvotes and is accepted. There's some other nuance, but that's why I downvoted.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker , as a moderator i am disappointed. The site specifically asks for comments to make a post better. I edited it to add that information, which I did not know was relevant.

Comment: @shog9 laid it out in another meta post beautifully. I'm on my phone, so I'm going to butcher it: if you want upvotes for a controversial topic on meta, it's not enough to lay out your argument, you have to make a strong and persuasive argument. Part of strong is making sure you do your research and your argument doesn't have any obvious holes.

Comment: downvotes are used differently on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ,  i wanted my question answered. Upvotes and downvotes is not what I am looking for. But if answering my question needs more detail, downvoting and running away does not help me or the community.

Comment: Flagging link-only answers only leads to frustration for everyone involved; you have a moderator [indicating we should flag such answers, and moderators should delete them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), but then a month later, [criticizing people for flagging link-only answers instead of editing them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251624/334849).  There's not much consistency in how these flags are handled, even when a link *can't* be easily edited into an answer.

Comment: Yes it is a link only answer. That doesn't necessarily mean we have to take any action against it. Clearly it was considered helpful by at least 32 viewers capable of upvoting, and probably many more. It's unlikely that such an answer would stand on a more recent question, but still possible. Deleting the answer wouldn't be improving the site in any way, instead, it would be removing information that has proven to be useful.

Comment: I've said this before too, @LittleBobbyTables: there's no consistency in the handling because there's no consistency in what's flagged. Consistency in the former without the latter would be a foolish hobgoblin or whatever that quote was - if, when flagging, you can't differentiate between a useful answer and noise, then someone else has to, and from that point on, the decision on what happens to the answer is theirs.

Comment: IMO, your flag was inappropriate because the post was from 2009 (6 years ago, in the early stages of SO), when such answers were somewhat acceptable, and because it has historic value even though it would not be considered appropriate now. It has many upvotes and was accepted (at the time it was posted). You didn't take into consideration the timeline. Your flag is like being sued now by someone in your office for sexual harassment because you went to high school 10 years ago and left a note in her locker that said she was "hot".

Answer (score 6):

It took me less than two minutes to edit that answer:

[image]

Not link-only anymore, is it.

> Both answers are highly upvoted and one is accepted as an answer; does this make a difference?

Interpreting the meaning of votes is always somewhat error-prone, but I'd have to say in this case it's reasonable to assume that at least a couple dozen people looking to make funky slider checkboxes have found that answer useful. So, probably worth taking a few minutes to spiff it up instead of casually discarding it...

Answer (score 5):

The topic *is this a link-only answer?* is indeed very subtle. Typically, the link-only answer is devoid of sense in case the link is broken. In case all other text apart from the link alnogside the answer is the rant the answer still remains a link-only answer.

So, the following two answers are link-only (at least to me):

- [Try this out](http://some.resource.com).
- You can try out many different things, but [this one](http://some.resource.com) helped me a lot.

That aside, another fine difference hides in what is requested in the question and what could potentially answer it.

So in case the question is *What can I do to solve X with Y. I've tried Z, but V is failing*, the following answers are link-only:

- [Blog post on V](http://some.resource.com).
- I also had the same problem and solved it by following the guidance [in this blog](http://some.resource.com).

In this case we'd expect to see a list of remedies instead of a plain link that could solve the problem potentially leading to nowhere.

Now imagine a question that sounds like *I want to achieve X and thus tried Y and Z that didn't help. Please help me find another way to solve my problem*. The answers could be

- [Library V](http://some.resource.com).
- I've used [framework Y](http://some.resource.com) and it yields excellent results.

Although both answers are *de jure* link-only, they are still the valid answers that do/could solve the initial issue and *de facto* should not be considered as link-only answers and flagged as such. I.e. they don't lose validity when the link gets stripped out. That's the question that fails to be on topic, but that's another story.

I see your flagged answers as falling within the second category and I wouldn't have flagged it as low-quality.

Comment: Thank you for the more in-depth reply. So you would **not** flag these as link only **or** low quality? Would you flag these answers at all or leave them?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D A few suggestions for you about these flags. 1. provide more than 3 words in your flag, the flag was just `link only answer...ok, but what do you want a mod to do that you can't. 2. Maybe leave a comment to the user asking them to elaborate on the answer since you feel it is low-quality....

Comment: @Jordan.J.D (continued) 3. Read Shogs9's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284218/426671), especially the final sentence **Be the user-moderator your participation has earned you the right to be, not a helpless supplicant.** - don't expect a moderator to step in and do something that you won't - the community could have handled this without a mod.

Comment: @bluefeet , thank you! I will do that next time. Should I say; "This is a link only answer. If the user does not elaborate, it should be deleted" ? Or should I not have used a custom flag at all?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D By using a custom moderator flag you are basically saying that the community can't handle this and a mod has to intervene.  These answers didn't need a mod and link answers **don't** need a mod involved. If you believe it is link-only, then flag it as "Not An Answer" or "Low Quality", it will go into the review queue and the community can deal with it. These are not things that a moderator needs to deal with, we have other most important issues to handle.

Comment: @bluefeet , thank you, that is basically the straightforward answer I was looking for. In this (general) case would "Not an Answer" or "Low Quality" be a *better* flag?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Yes, because mods don't need to be involved. :)

Comment: @bluefeet , I think I worded my last comment incorrectly. I meant to ask about which flag to choose between "Not an Answer" and "Low Quality"

Comment: @Jordan.J.D If it has a positive score, you won't be able to use Low Quality - both flags will send the post to the review queue.  I'd suggest reading some of the many posts on Meta about NAA or VLQ - unfortunately it depends on many different things - it's not clear-cut.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental test for a link-only answer is this: if you strip away the (presumed opaque) URL and markup, does the remaining text serve as any kind of answer at all? If not, then it's a link-only answer.

Examples can be drawn from skuntsel's answer, which is also broadly correct.

With that said, the usual advice I've seen is not to flag link-only with custom, but just to use NAA. The only exception I'm aware of would be if it's not immediately clear *why* it's NAA, but true link-only shouldn't have trouble with that.

Answer (score -3):

[this is link only](http://www.linkonly.com/)

This is definetly not [link](http://www.linkonly.com/) only... obviously!

---

Beside the fact, that to be link-only an answer does obviously need to contain only a link, it does also call out "IPhone checkboxes" as solution hint, which could be googled, even if the given link would brake.

But it is a not very great answer, indeed.

Comment: by that argument, if my answer is "look at [link](http://www.linkonly.com/) " it would be valid?

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't be an answer, as long as I wouldn't ask explicitly for the link, but it would not be link only. In the worst case you can make a valid answer that way, like the one you flagged. A valid answer of poor quality that I'd vote down...

Comment: So flagging the answers is correct, but I am using an incorrect flag?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D "link only" doesn't convey a problem. It's like saying "the sky is grey." Tell us what you want us to do in your custom flag. Tell us why.

Comment: Sometimes it is, sometimes a down-vote would be the correct behavior... In your cited example I'd go with the downvote

Comment: This is wrong. If I post an answer that says nothing but *See [here](http://example.com) for code*, it's a link only answer. The fact that in earlier times the post in the question was acceptable does not make it appropriate according to the current guidelines. Your second example is in fact a link-only answer, as it contains no relevant information other than the link. By your standards, I could post *blah blah [link](http://example.com) blah* and it would not be a link-only answer.